# exit(3) hangs in Linux C++

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, exit, cross-compiling

I have a small C++ program that pings other machines on a network and send status information out over another network. The program runs as a daemon, so the startup process forks off a child and then calls `exit`. This program is cross-compiled to run on two different architectures: x86 and ARM. The GCC versions are 4.4 and 3.5 respectively. I can compile and run the program on x86 and it works flawlessly. However, when I run the program on the ARM, it hangs any time I call `exit`, not just after the `fork`. I have no functions registered with `atexit` or `on_exit`. The following are my includes:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include "telnet_client.h"

#include <stdint.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <customlib1.h>
#include <customlib2.h>
```

The following are my GCC commands:

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wall -DBUILDSTAMP="\"`date '+%F %T'`\"" -g -ggdb -O0 -I/usr/local/arm/arm-2007q1/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/include -DEMBEST_ARM -I/usr/local/share/arm/boost/src -I../include/ -I../include_rms -c can_wifid.cpp -o can_wifid.o
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wall -DBUILDSTAMP="\"`date '+%F %T'`\"" -g -ggdb -O0 -I/usr/local/arm/arm-2007q1/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/include -DEMBEST_ARM -I/usr/local/share/arm/boost/src -I../include/ -I../include_rms -c telnet_client.cpp -o telnet_client.o
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wall -DBUILDSTAMP="\"`date '+%F %T'`\"" -g -ggdb -O0 -I/usr/local/arm/arm-2007q1/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/include -DEMBEST_ARM -I/usr/local/share/arm/boost/src can_wifid.o telnet_client.o -L/usr/local/arm/arm-2007q1/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib  -L../lib_embest_arm -L../lib_rms_embest_arm -Wl,-Bdynamic -lutilities -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lcanprovider -lembestcan -o can_wifid
```

Even just parsing my command line parameters with `getopt` then calling `exit` after a version message causes this problem (simplest case in my program). Has anybody ever experienced anything like this where `exit` just hangs ?

EDIT: Added code for the first part of the main function:

```
struct canwifid_options
{
public:
bool daemon_mode;
int verbosity;

canwifid_options()
{
    this->daemon_mode = false;
    this->verbosity = LOG_NOTICE;
}
};

static canwifid_options options;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
int LoggingOptions = LOG_CONS|LOG_NDELAY|LOG_PID;
pid_t Pid;

ParseCommandLine(argc, argv);

if (!options.daemon_mode)
{
    LoggingOptions |= LOG_PERROR;
}

openlog("can_wifid", LoggingOptions, LOG_USER);

setlogmask(LOG_UPTO(options.verbosity));

if (options.daemon_mode)
{
    Pid = fork();

    if (Pid < 0)
    {
        // couldn't fork off and create a child process
        // log it, %m is a special syslog flag
        syslog(LOG_CRIT, "Unable to create daemon [Error: %m]");
        exit(ESRCH);
    }
    else if (Pid > 0)
    {
        // we're the parent, so we're done and out of here
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    else
    {
        // we're the child, take control of the session.
        setsid();

        // change to the root directory so we don't retain unnecessary control
        // of any mounted volumes
        chdir("/");

        // clear our file mode creation mask
        umask(0000);
    }
}
else
{
    // get our process ID
    Pid = getpid();
}

syslog(LOG_INFO, "Running as %s", options.daemon_mode ? "daemon" : "standalone");

    // Network code here, snipped for clarity
}
```

And there ParseCommandLine function:

```
static void ParseCommandLine(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int c;

while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "dhqvDV?")) > 0)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case 'd':
            options.daemon_mode = true;
            break;
        case 'V':
            VersionMessage(argv);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            break;
        case 'q':
            options.verbosity = LOG_WARNING;
            break;
        case 'v':
            options.verbosity = LOG_INFO;
            break;
        case 'D':
            options.verbosity = LOG_DEBUG;
            break;
        case 'h':
        case '?':
        default:
            HelpMessage(argv);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            break;
    }
}

return; //done
}
```

Comment: Let's see the code from fork() to exit().

Comment: Have you already tried "Hello, World" cross-compiled? Does program crash if you just return from main? If you can make non-crashing version, expand it line by line to produce most simple crashing version.

Comment: Note that the runtime usually adds atexit handlers, e.g. to close open FILE* or run destructors of global C++ objects. It might provide insight if you're able to capture `strace` output when the process hangs, or hook up a debugger and generate a backtrace. The other thing to note is that forking() threaded programs is very dangerous, as it incurs a lot of potential for race conditions in locks (not just your own, but internal mutexes used by malloc, FILE* etc.) - this depends on when the fork is done though.

Comment: @hyde Yes, the program still hangs at exit(3) when replacing the whole of the main() function with just a printf() and exit(). Also, the program doesn't crash, it just hangs.

Comment: How is the program being run on ARM?  From a shell?

Comment: @wallyk Yes, I'm just running it from a shell: can_wifid -d to put it into daemon mode.

Comment: @nos Unfortunately the ARM machine is an embedded board, and strace isn't available. I'd have to find the source and cross-compile it, which may take some time, but I can give it a shot.

Comment: I seem to have narrowed down the problem. As soon as I comment out any boost related code, the program's fine and it can exit. I'll have to focus on that, perhaps I've done something wrong during cross-compilation, or missed a header.

Comment: It took me a moment to realize that `exit(3)` refers to section 3 of the man page; I was wondering why you were calling `exit()` with an argument of `3`. It might be clearer to drop the man page section references. (And `fork()` is in section 2, not 3.)

Comment: Thank you for the correction, and suggestion.

Comment: Does your program have any global or static variables whose destructors might hang?  (It might be interesting to replace exit() with _exit() and see if that makes a difference, as the latter won't try to run cleanup code, it will just rudely end the process)

Comment: @BillPringlemeir I was mistaken in my original post. For my ARM compiler, I'm currently using arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc version 4.2.0 prerelease from CodeSourcery

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `BOOST` issue.  Boost can have libraries on the target.  Make sure the boost version on your host is the same.

Comment: @BillPringlemeir It is, I cross-compiled the boost libraries myself and put them on the target in a folder I've verified is in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. The version I'm using is Boost 1.53.0 (shared)

Comment: Can you upload smallest reproducible binary somewhere? Including boost lib.

Comment: Specifically it was the boost/thread.hpp header that was doing it. I'm at work in the middle of trying to deploy some stuff, and had to come up with a work around. I still want to solve this problem because I'm going to be doing a lot of work in the future where I will need boost, especially with threading. I will upload a binary as soon as I can, I will be getting back to this hopefully today, definitely tomorrow.

Comment: @auselen What's the best way for me to get you the binary and the libraries ?

Comment: upload it one of those file hosts (rapidshare, etc)

Comment: @auselen You can find a tar.gz containing the sample code, makefile and binaries of the library and compiled program here: http://rapidshare.com/files/1494143818/boost_test.tar.gz Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

An issue I ran into once is that calling `exit` attempts to exit and calls global destructors WITHOUT trying to unwind the stack or call any destructors for local objects on the stack.  This can easily manifest if you have any sort of locks that might be required for global destructors.  For example, this program deadlocks in exit (actually in the global dtor):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex  lock;

class A {
public:
    A() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> acquire(lock);
        std::cout << "ctor A" << std::endl;
    }
    ~A() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> acquire(lock);
        std::cout << "dtor A" << std::endl;
    }
};

A a;

int main()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> acquire(lock);
    exit(0);
}
```

Now your problem may be something completely different, but there's a strong possibility its related to something in a global destructor that is misbehaving because some object on the stack has not been destroyed properly.

If you want to exit while unwinding the stack properly (which is required for RAII structured code), you can't call exit.  Instead you need to throw an exception which is caught (only) in main and causes main to return.

Comment: I'm not currently using any locks for anything, but I'll keep your solution in mind. Thank you very much for your suggestion Chris.

Comment: @AlexMarshall: Things other than locks can manifest in this same way -- the key issue is that objects on the stack are not being properly destroyed when you call `exit`, leading to problems in global destructors.  If you can figure out more precisely where it is hanging (rather than just 'after calling exit') you might be able to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I got the main idea, but what I was trying to say was that I can reproduce the problem with just a printf and an exit. It seems that just including the hpp file is enough to cause the problem.